# get the ids when more than one checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get the ids of every checkbox checked and save into var:

this is my code:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="p1_perro" class="checks" name="p1[]" value="p1_perro" />
<label>Perro</label>
<br />

<input type="checkbox" id="p1_gato" class="checks" name="p1[]" value="p1_gato" />
<label>Gato</label>
<br />

<input type="checkbox" id="p1_pajaro" class="checks" name="p1[]" value="p1_pajaro" />
<label>Pájaro</label>
<br />

<input type="checkbox" id="p1_roedor" class="checks" name="p1[]" value="p1_roedor" />
<label>Roedor</label>
<br />

<input type="checkbox" id="p1_reptil" class="checks" name="p1[]" value="p1_reptil" />
<label>Reptil</label>
<br />

<input type="checkbox" id="p1_otros" class="checks" name="p1[]" value="p1_otros" />
<label id="q_1">Otros</label>
```

and this is the javascript:

```
$("#p1_perro, #p1_pajaro, #p1_roedor, #p1_reptil, #p1_otros").live("click", function() {
    var valueAnimal = this.id;
    if(valueAnimal == 'p1_perro'){
      $( "#otroAnimal" ).text( "¿Que edad tiene tu perro?" );
    }

    if(valueAnimal == 'p1_pajaro'){
      $( "#otroAnimal" ).text( "¿Que edad tiene tu p&aacute;jaro?" );
    }

    if(valueAnimal == 'p1_roedor'){
      $( "#otroAnimal" ).text( "¿Que edad tiene tu roedor?" );
    }

    if(valueAnimal == 'p1_reptil'){
      $( "#otroAnimal" ).text( "¿Que edad tiene tu reptil?" );
    }

    if(valueAnimal == 'p1_otros'){
      $( "#otroAnimal" ).text( "¿Que edad tiene tu animal?" );
    }

    if (this.checked) {
        $("#bloque_perro").show(); 
    }else{
        $("#bloque_perro").hide(); 
    }
});
```

in this example just I can get one id when user select one more than one checkbox.

Comment: `.live` is removed in lastest jQuery's versions, use `.on()` with event delegation.

Comment: hey did you get your ans/

Answer (score 0):

This will give you all `Selected Checkbox` IDs in variable `selected`.

```
var selected = new Array();
$('#checkboxes input:checked').each(function() {
    selected.push($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Comment: `$(this).attr('name')` should be `$(this).attr('id')`

Comment: hi, thanks for help me with this, how can i display, for example, the name of two cheboxes selected? thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

you are using jquery then why not use `:checked` selector

[check demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mayekarsaurabh/7w8TC/39/)

Answer (score 0):

try these code :

```
<fieldset id="cb-group">
    <legend>Checkboxes group</legend>

    <input type="checkbox" id="p1_perro" class="checks" name="p1[]" value="p1_perro" />
    <label>Perro</label>
    <br />

    <input type="checkbox" id="p1_gato" class="checks" name="p1[]" value="p1_gato" />
    <label>Gato</label>
    <br />

    <input type="checkbox" id="p1_pajaro" class="checks" name="p1[]" value="p1_pajaro" />
    <label>Pájaro</label>
    <br />

    <input type="checkbox" id="p1_roedor" class="checks" name="p1[]" value="p1_roedor" />
    <label>Roedor</label>
    <br />

    <input type="checkbox" id="p1_reptil" class="checks" name="p1[]" value="p1_reptil" />
    <label>Reptil</label>
    <br />

    <input type="checkbox" id="p1_otros" class="checks" name="p1[]" value="p1_otros" />
    <label id="q_1">Otros</label>

</fieldset>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var cbSelector = "#cb-group input[type=\"checkbox\"]",
        selectedIds = [];

    $(cbSelector).change(function (args) {

        var selectedIds = [];
        $(cbSelector + ":checked").each(function (i, e) {
            selectedIds.push($(e).val());
        });

        console.log("Selected ids : " + selectedIds.join(", "));

    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could keep track of each check/uncheck but it's easier and safer just to generate a list of checked checkboxes on any click event...

```
$(".checks").on("click", function(){
  var all=[];
  $(".checks").each(function(){
    if (this.checked)
      all.push(this.id);
  });
  alert(all);
});
```

http://jsbin.com/ESoRoQIs/1/

Answer (score 0):

Simplest would be,

```
$('input[name*=p1]').on('change', function () {
    console.log($('input[name*=p1]:checked').map(function () {
        return $(this).attr('id')
    }).get());
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Dipak1991/xEknB/)